# Solving for t in an exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Solve for $t$ in the equation:
$$(1+t)e^{-t}=0.05$$
This is where I have reached.
$$(1+t)e^{-t}=0.05$$
$$1+t=0.05e^t$$
$$\ln(1+t)=\ln0.05e^t$$
$$\ln1+\ln t=\ln0.05+\ln e^t$$
$$\ln t=\ln0.05+t$$
I am stucked

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: is this $$e^{-T(1+T)}=0.05$$?

Comment: No. I have made the necessary corrections. It's e^ (-T)

Comment: the logarithm of the sum is not the sum of the logarithms

Comment: there is no closed solution for this, use numerical methods

Comment: Numerical methods...how?

Comment: @AshalleySamuel Newton raphson method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method If you have any questions about this method feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
$$
(1+t)e^{-t} = \frac{1}{20}
\\
(-1-t)e^{-t} = \frac{-1}{20}
\\
(-1-t)e^{-1-t} = \frac{-1}{20e}
\\
-1-t = W\left(\frac{-1}{20e}\right)
\\
1+t = -W\left(\frac{-1}{20e}\right)
\\
t = -W\left(\frac{-1}{20e}\right)-1
$$
All complex solutions are obtained by taking all branches of W.  The real solutions are
$$
-W_0\left(\frac{-1}{20e}\right)-1 \approx -.981258037995
\\
-W_{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{20e}\right)-1 \approx 4.74386451839
$$

Comment: (+1) nice use of Lambert function, its kinda obvious, but i think not to the OP.

Comment: So how do you get the figures in using Lambert W function. I understand only to where the figures were obtained

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the beautiful Lambert function, just consider the most general problem where you look for the zero(s) of function $$f(t)=(1+t)e^{-t}-a$$ $$f'(t)=-te^{-t}$$ $$f''(t)=(t-1)e^{-t}$$ So, the function increases when $t<0$, goes through a maximum when $t=0$ (by the second derivative test), decreases when $t>0$.

At the maximum, we have $f(0)=1-a$; so, if $a<1$, there will be two real roots (one negative and one positive). If $a=1$, a double root $t=0$ and  if $a>1$, no  root at all.

If you graph the function for $a=0.05$, you will see that there is one root close to $t=-1$ and another one close to $t=5$. You then have all the elements to start Newton method which will give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & -1.00000000000000000000 \\
 1 & -0.98160602794142788392 \\
 2 & -0.98125816020529694931 \\
 3 & -0.98125803799504305042 \\
 4 & -0.98125803799502797244
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_n \\
 0 & 5.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 4.7158684089742339658 \\
 2 & 4.7435578246859564746 \\
 3 & 4.7438644812774523864 \\
 4 & 4.7438645183905778323 \\
 5 & 4.7438645183905783759
\end{array}
\right)$$ These are the solutions for twenty significants figures.

Concerning the estimates of the solutions (for $a<1$), we can gnerate estimates approximating the function $f(x)$ using, say, a $[2,3]$ Padé approximant. Solving for the roots of numerator, we should get
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{2 \left(42-24a-18 a^2\pm\sqrt{-131 a^4-3386 a^3-4356 a^2+3194 a+4679}\right)}{13 a^2+114 a+53}$$ For $a=0.05$, this will give as estimates  $t_1=-0.978$ and $t_2=3.754$.

Comment: Am trying to use the numerical methods approach. But how do i get the initial value for "t"?

Comment: @AshalleySamuel. See my edit.